# Using object reference to get methods from another class

Tags: java

So I have a concrete class and an abstract class and I am trying to access methods from the concrete class from the abstract one. Store currently contains many getters that the member class needs. Currently get null pointer exception.

```
public abstract class members{

// Trying to refrence the store object
Store store;

public void someMethod(){
    // I want to be able to access all the methods from the store class
    // eg
    store.showVideoCollection();
    }
}

public class store {
// This class has already been instantiated, just one object for it.

public void showVideoCollection(){
    // Stuff here
}
public void otherMethod(){
    // Stuff here
    }
}
```

EDIT:

In the main method

```
public class start {
     public start() {
     store = new Store(); // Don't want to create more than 1 store object.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You never initialized store ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to store a `Store` instance you must instantiate it. As is, you declare the variable `store` but you never initialize it (so it's `null`). I think you wanted something like

```
// Trying to refrence the store object
Store store = new Store(); // <-- create a Store and assign it to store.
```

Alternatively, you could make `Store` a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The linked Wikipedia page says (in part) *the **singleton pattern** is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object.*

```
public final class Store {
    public static Store getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    private static final Store _instance = new Store();

    private Store() {
    }

    public void showVideoCollection(){
        // Stuff here
    }

    public void otherMethod(){
        // Stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew I was missing something small like this. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way I can access the one 'store' object that's already created instead of creating a new one? Problem is I am trying to access items that have already been added to the store class. So when I create a new object of it in 'members' it gets rid of all the previous entries (understandably).

Seems like I need a getter just to that one store instance, but not quite sure how to achieve it.

Comment: You could make `store` a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). It's hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the solution here. Sorry if I was unclear.